# For random variables $X,Y$, show $E[X E(Y | \mathscr{G}) ] = E[E(X | \mathscr{G}) Y ]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

> Show that for random variables $X,Y$ on probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, for any $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{G} \subset \mathscr{F}$ that:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   E[X E(Y | \mathscr{G}) ] = E[E(X | \mathscr{G}) E(Y | \mathscr{G}) ] = E[E(X | \mathscr{G}) Y ]
> \end{align*}

FYI, this is from Karatzas + Shreve, on page 43, in the give solution to problem 4.11.

Of course, $E[E(X | \mathscr{G})] = E[X]$. And when $X \in \mathscr{G}$, $E(X | \mathscr{G}) = X$. But in the general case, I don't see how to prove the relationship given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}E[XE[Y|\mathscr{G}]]&\stackrel{\textrm{TP}}{=}E[E[XE[Y|\mathscr{G}]|\mathscr{G}]]=\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{Meas.}}{=}E[E[X|\mathscr{G}]E[Y|\mathscr{G}]]=\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{Meas.}}{=}E[E[E[X|\mathscr{G}]Y|\mathscr{G]}]=\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{TP}}{=}E[E[X|\mathscr{G}]Y]\end{aligned}$$
where $\textrm{TP}$ is the tower property and $\textrm{Meas.}$ indicates the fact that if $\sigma(Z)\subseteq \mathscr{Z}$ then $E[ZH|\mathscr{Z}]=ZE[H|\mathscr{Z}]$.

Comment: wow, so simple, when you explain it. Thank you :)